# Assigning values to a particular cell in a multidimensional array (python)

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

If I have a 6-dimensional matrix,

`data = np.zeros((1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))`

Is there a way to write a value to a specific dimension, and only that dimension? For example, I would like to write "3" to only 5th dimension. I've tried a few ways, and cannot seem to find a good solution..

Comment: Because the length of each dimension is 1, your 6-dimensional array contains just one element, `data[0,0,0,0,0,0]`.

Comment: what if it was a greater size? Say, np.zeros((5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5))?

Comment: I'm not sure what *'write "3" to only 5th dimension'* actually means, but the answer is almost surely *'the same way you would write "3" to only the second dimension'* of, say, a 2-dimensional array.

Comment: So, could you use a 2-dimensional array to give a concrete example of what you want to do?  Then we'll generalize to n dimensions.